# Error in constructor or array or the for loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
// The Person constructor
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// Now we can make an array of peoples
var family = new Array();
family[0] = Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = Person("timmy", 6);

// loop through our new array
for ( i=0; i < family.length; i++; ) {
    console.log(family[i].name)
};
```

The expected output of this script is:

```
alice
bob
michelle
timmy
```

But the output is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (anonymous function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `new` keyword for each `Person` added, and remove the extra `;` in the `for`-loop (after the `i++`)

```
// Now we can make an array of people
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);

// loop through our new array
for ( i=0; i < family.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(family[i].name);       // Also, added a semicolon here. Not required, but it's good practice to close your lines.
};
```

This will now log:

> alice
>   bob
>   michelle
>   timmy

Answer (score 0):

```
// Our Person constructor
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// Now we can make an array of people
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);

console.info(family);
// loop through our new array
for ( i=0; i < family.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(family[i].name)
};
```

Comment: This is correct, but you should add some comments about what you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
// Our Person constructor
var Person = function(name,age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
};

// Now we can make an array of people
var family = new Array();
    family[0] = new Person("alice",40);
    family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
    family[2] = new Person("michelle",8);
    family[3] = new Person("timmy",6);

// loop through our new array
for (var famloop in family) {
    console.log(family[famloop].name);
}
```